# Groovy-Postbuild-Plugin execution on remote slave fails, complains about File Not Found

Tags: plugins, jenkins

The script i am using the in postbuild-step is as follows, I am trying to extract the MAVEN_VERSION from the file and it doesnt find the file on remote slave, however when i execute the same on local slave the same works fine,
So i believe the Plugin needs to be updated to have a VirtualChannel open to the remote workspace for parsing file, I havent looked at the code yet but if anyone has a quick fix, can some one help with this
**Environment Details**
Running Jenkins 1.625.3.1
groovy-postbuild-plugin - 2.2.2
JDK1.8.0_72
Tomcat_8.0.30

```
import jenkins.util.*;
import jenkins.model.*;
def thr = Thread.currentThread();
def currentBuild = thr?.executable;
def workspace = currentBuild.getModuleRoot().absolutize().toString();
def project = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("$workspace/pom.xml"))
def param = new hudson.model.StringParameterValue("MAVEN_VERSION",    project.version.toString())
currentBuild.addAction(new hudson.model.ParametersAction(param));
```

Error in log -

```
ERROR: Failed to evaluate groovy script.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /prod/jenkins/test-slave/workspace/MYProjectBuild/pom.xml (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parse(XmlSlurper.java:160)
at groovy.util.XmlSlurper$parse.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:6)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:580)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:618)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:589)
at  org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:166)
at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildRecorder.perform(GroovyPostbuildRecorder.java:362)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:726)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
at      hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:671)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
```

Comment: instead of Thread.currentThread you can use manager.build. As for fetching remote files take a look at hudson.FilePath; and you can get the ComputerChannel from currentBuild.builtOn.computer.channel or currentBuiild.workspace.channel

Comment: Can you provide a little more details around using manager.build() and also can you point me to some documentation where i can read about groovy and jenkins operations, i am new to groovy and would like to learn it.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by tweaking the code, Thanks to @izzekil for suggesting the hudson.FilePath was able to figure it out. Hope this helps anyone who has a similar need.

```
import jenkins.util.*;
import jenkins.model.*;
def thr = Thread.currentThread();
def currentBuild = thr?.executable;

if(manager.build.workspace.isRemote())
{
    channel = manager.build.workspace.channel;
    def fp = new hudson.FilePath(channel, manager.build.workspace.toString() + "/pom.xml");
    def project = new XmlSlurper().parseText(fp.readToString());
    def param = new hudson.model.StringParameterValue("MAVEN_VERSION", project.version.toString());
    currentBuild.addAction(new hudson.model.ParametersAction(param));
}
else
{
    def workspace = currentBuild.getModuleRoot().absolutize().toString();
    def project = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("$workspace/pom.xml"))
    def param = new hudson.model.StringParameterValue("MAVEN_VERSION", project.version.toString())
    currentBuild.addAction(new hudson.model.ParametersAction(param));
}
```